# Save RTSP stream continuously into multi mp4 files with specific length (10 minutes) in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, rtsp

I'm recording RTSP stream from camera into `.mp4` files using ffmpeg and I want to roll it into multi files with 10 minutes long every videos.

Currently I have a solution for this: I'm setting a time length '00:10:00', after it finished then I will restart below command with new process.
Sample:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i <rtsp_url> -acodec copy -vcodec  copy  -t 00:10:00 D:\video_test.mp4
```

But this solution makes camera becoming unstable, RTSP stream uasually corrupted with this error:

```
rtsp://10.96.41.14:9024/user=xxxx_password=xxx_channel=1_stream=0.sdp?real_stream: Operation not permitted
```

I want to find better solution to keep connection to RTSP stream continuously (not create new process with a `-t` flag).

Does anyone have better idea to keep recording stream continuously?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FFmpeg has a [segment](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) muxer you can use for this.

Basic form is

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i <rtsp_url> -c copy -f segment -segment_time 600 stream_piece_%d.mp4
```

Note that the segment muxer splits at keyframes, so there are likely to be small deviations in the segment durations obtained.

Comment: thank @Gyan I tried to use this segment and do you think it is good way to record stream from camera 24/7 all the time (splits at keyframes).

Comment: I know people using it to split satellite feeds continuously.

Answer (score 4):

I want to extend the answer from @Gyan as my solution that I'm using.

In my case, I want to segment stream into normal videos (it can be playback) and video starts at 0 minute every hour of clock. So I'm using option `reset_timestamps` and `segment_atclocktime`.

Below is my full ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i <rtsp_url> -f segment -strftime 1 \ 
    -segment_time 00:10:00 -segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_clocktime_offset 30 \
    -segment_format mp4 -an -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 \ 
    record_%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.mp4
```

Comment: I get `Unrecognized option 'segment_clocktime_offset'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`

Comment: Maybe you should check the ffmpeg version or document here https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html with search key is "segment_clocktime_offset"